# Error using SystemVerilog interfaces and iverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench, iverilog

I am trying to write a testbench for a simple PISO register design. In the testbench and design, I am using an interface to encapsulate all the signals to and from the design (with modport for TB and DUT). But, when I compile it with icarus-verilog, I get these errors:

```
iverilog -g2012 piso_tb.sv
./piso.sv:25: syntax error
./piso.sv:1: Errors in port declarations.
piso_tb.sv:9: syntax error
piso_tb.sv:9: error: Invalid module instantiation
```

I tried changing the flag to -g2005-sv, but it gives the same error. Here are my design and TB files:

`piso.sv` : Design + Interface

```
interface my_piso;

    logic [7:0] din;
    logic resetn;
    logic dout;
    logic din_en;

    modport TB (
        output din,
        output resetn,
        input dout,
        output din_en
    );

    modport DUT (
        input din,
        input resetn,
        input din_en,
        output dout
    );

endinterface


module model (input clk, my_piso piso_if);
  reg [7:0] temp;

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(!piso_if.resetn) begin
      temp <= 0;
    end else begin
      if(piso_if.din_en) begin
        temp <= piso_if.din;
      end else begin
        temp <= temp >> 1;
      end
    end
  end

  assign piso_if.dout = temp & 1'b1;

endmodule
```

---

`piso_tb.sv` : Testbench

```
`include "piso.sv"

module model_tb;

    reg clk;

    always #5 clk = ~clk;

    my_piso piso_if;

    model dut(
        .clk(clk),
        .piso_if(piso_if.DUT)
    );

    initial begin
        $dumpfile("model.vcd");
        $dumpvars;
    end

    initial begin
        $display("time\tclk\tresetn\tdin_en\tdin\tdout");
        $monitor("%d\t%b\t%b\t%b\t%b\t%b", $time, clk, piso_if.resetn, piso_if.din_en, piso_if.din, piso_if.dout);
    end

    initial begin
        clk <= 0;
        piso_if.resetn <= 0;
        piso_if.din_en <= 0;
        piso_if.din <= 0;

        @(posedge clk);

        piso_if.resetn <= 1;
        piso_if.din_en <= 1;
        piso_if.din <= $random;

        @(posedge clk);

        repeat(10) begin
            piso_if.din_en <= 0;
            @(posedge clk);
        end

        $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

I also tried shifting the interface code into a separate file, but it gives the same error. Is there any syntax error that I am committing? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The testbench module has a syntax error.  When instantiating an `interface`, it is required to have a port list after the instance name, just like with `module` instances.

Change:

```
my_piso piso_if;
```

to:

```
my_piso piso_if ();
```

It is legal for the port list to be empty.

---

However, this does not fix the other `iverilog` syntax errors you are seeing.  `iverilog` does not support many SystemVerilog features.  If you want to use this syntax, you need to either try updating `iverilog` to a newer version, or use another simulator.  There are other simulators on the EDAPlayground site.  For example, the code runs on the [Cadence simulator there](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Tm4f).